# Imitate Google Maps mapTypeControl Custom Control

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know how to exactly match the google maps `mapTypeControl` button style (concerning ui/css)? I found a nice [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomExample) but the buttons do not match the default google style. Is there an easy way to get exactly the current google maps button styles or do I have to manualy try to match the `current` styles (can be different in every new release which would be kind of a pain in the... you know what I mean).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick look into the Chrome Developer console reveals the following inline styles (there are no classes or id-s assigned to any of the buttons). Also notice that this element has an empty no-styler floating wrapper that also holds the button menu (the terrain button).

For the Map button:

```
direction: ltr; 
overflow: hidden; 
text-align: center; 
position: relative; 
color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
-webkit-user-select: none; 
font-size: 13px; 
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
padding: 1px 6px; 
border: 1px solid rgb(113, 123, 135); 
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 2px 4px; 
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 2px 4px; 
font-weight: bold; min-width: 29px; 
background-position: initial initial; 
background-repeat: initial initial;
```

For the Satellite button the only style that differs is the font-weight

Comment: That is what I did before. Isn't that just what the current browser can display? What about old browsers that do not support rgba? Since there is no id's or classes assigned there must be the original ruleset in the javascript or something. So I am still looking for a more detailed version of the css code.

Comment: Thing is that the majority of the Google apps use adaptive CSS. That is, if the browser does not support rgba, then a fallback to rgb is used. There is no javascript that makes the rgb transparent just for the sake of it. Same applies to border-radius and shadows. If the browser does not support either one, it's gonna render it with square corners and/or without shadows, and you have to make that also look good. Open google.com with an old browser (like ie7) and you'll see that the buttons are square and flat. I'm gonna try and find a better version of this CSS for you.

Comment: You do not have to do the dirty job for me, but if you find out anything about how to more generally apply the google styles/retrieve them please edit your posting. I will go for your version in the meantime.